# SQL: Efficient and fast way to select million of records except given records

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server. Facing problem with handling large amount of data in SQL Query. I want to select those records from ITEM table which are not in my given list.

Let me elaborate.
I have ITEM table having ITEM_CODE as column.
It contains several million of records.
and populating some item codes from other source, for instance a file. 
So i want to select those records from ITEM table which are not in that populated list.

Like,

```
SELECT ITEM_CODE FROM ITEM WHERE ITEM_CODE NOT IN ('I1', 'I2', 'I3',.......);
```

Using IN is cumbersome task, and take lot of time. then i used other way, like this,

```
SELECT ITEM_CODE FROM ITEM WHERE NOT (ITEM_CODE = 'I1' OR ITEM_CODE = 'I2' AND .....)
```

- Note:  .... means million of parameters.

This way also takes lot of time. another way i used,

```
    SELECT T.ITEM_CODE FROM ITEM T LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ITEM_CODE FROM ITEM T1 
    WHERE T1.ITEM_CODE ='I1' OR T1.ITEM_CODE ='I2') AS T2
    on T.ITEM_CODE = T2.ITEM_CODE WHERE T2.ITEM_CODE IS NULL
```

This way improve little performance, but still not satisfactory.

Is there any way to do it fast ?
Please suggest me some solution to this. 

 Any answer will be appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: You should avoid using Indian words like lac, not everyone understands them.

Comment: What on Earth is a LAC?

Comment: Its 0.1 Million @DavidG did you tried running explain plan for your query?

Comment: Oh I see. So you are probably best off inserting those values into a database table (permanent or temporary) and joining that table to your ITEM table.

Comment: Where those million parameters come from?

Comment: The problem with such a long string, is that SQL server needs to parse the whole text, character by character. What api interface are you using to talk to the server? Many api (.NET for example) have support for parametrised queries. Try 'where not in (@list)' with a parametrised list. Also, integer comparison will be faster, so if you could encode your 'i1, i2..' Into some integer, that will help as well

Comment: @taoufik I am using Spring-MyBatis persistence framework. Using IN is heavy and slow. and may be IN have some parameter list limit, i don't know actually!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP(ITEM_CODE VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #TMP
VALUES('I1'), ('I2'), etc ....

SELECT T.ITEM_CODE 
FROM ITEM T 
    LEFT JOIN #TMP T2 ON T.ITEM_CODE = T2.ITEM_CODE
WHERE T2.ITEM_CODE IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT T.ITEM_CODE 
FROM ITEM T
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM #TMP T2
    WHENRE T2.ITEM_CODE = T.ITEM_CODE)
```

You can even create an index on the temp table

```
CREATE INDEX _temp ON #TMP (ITEM_CODE)
```

Comment: Spock, Thank you. This is probably good solution which i also thought. But problem is, i am getting those 'I1', 'I2' values at Java side from CSV file, and i have to pass it to MyBatis Mappers. So, creating TEMP table is not a big deal, but inserting those million of items in it, wouldn't be like lumbering process ?

Comment: In that case, have a look at the bulk insert, openquery, or bcp methods. That will be your best bet to read a large amount of data from a file into a table

Comment: Ah, thank you. Bulk insert is always little hard task because of some DB dependency. Regarding openquery and bcp, are totally unwitting concepts to me.

Comment: Hello Spock, creating TEMP table is really now big deal for me..! I though it's easy as i did in PostgreSQL. but i am not able to find for SQL server. I want to create TEMP table that stay during transaction and automatically deleted at end of transaction. I am using Spring-Mybats, also can use JDBC if required. Please help.

Comment: If you create a temp table with a double #, it will span transactions. I.E. CREATE TABLE ##TEMP. You will have to manually drop it though, or it will remain until the server is restarted. Also, you'll have to manually manage the session scope of the table, as the table will be visible to all connections.